# vehicle tracking with haar-like features and camshift

Tags: opencv, object-detection, haar-classifier

I am trying to track vehicles using a moving camera. Vehicles are detected by [Haar Feature-based Cascade Classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier) in OpenCV. I use pre-trained dataset [here](http://lars.mec.ua.pt/public/Media/HaarFeatures_RoadFilms/HaarFeaturesTests/CarsRear/). According to the Object Tracking [survey](http://crcv.ucf.edu/papers/Object%20Tracking.pdf) (2006), there are three categories to track objects:  points or neighborhoods, kernels or shapes, or tracking can be based on the object's silhouette or its permiter. I think my approach falls into the second category. Therefore, I tried camshift algorithm first.

However, during the detection phase, I got lots of false positives, which makes the tracking inefficient. My question is how do you eliminate false positives?

I am thinking to calculate the histogram of the all bounding boxes (including false positives) for each frame. Then, do the same for next frame and compare the histograms to create the confidence level. Do you think it is a good idea?

I also have ideas to apply processioning before detection (e.g.:segmentation basckground/foreground subtraction, thresholding etc..) but these are more suitable for stationary cameras than moving cameras. I need to continue with Haar for a while, at least give a shot. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a broad question with a myraid of approaches, but the basic one is that you need a few things to build a solid tracker:

- a good input (moving camera)
- a good feature / region descripter (you chose  haar wavelet based method)
- a good comparison metric for discripters (don't know what you are doing here)

generically you need to stabilize your input through an image registration process
reference your library of discripters
calculate a metric of those discripters against your registered input image

reducing false positives is dependent upon your approach, but typically you group together the false positives and find out where in the algorithm they are originating from the most (many will originate at different places) and then change that part of the algorithm to cull them better.

your options are:

- register the images if they aren't already (this will remove the false positives from relative motion)
- examine the algorithm to identify the largest source of false positives and modify it accordingly
- get better training data to match against (if your training data doesn't match the real world data this will never work)
- try a different approach (SIFT,SURF, GLO, Fourier Mellin Transform etc.)

that's as specific as I can be given your provided information. I hope it helps.